# How can I constrain Vinyl / Composite Records?

Tags: haskell, types, hlist, extensible, vinyl

I have an extensible Vinyl / Composite record (similar to HList, Frames...), and I would like to generate the tuples of keys/values, such as

```
tuplify '[String :-> Whatevs, ...] :: [(String, String)]
```

This is surprisingly hard. [**original gist**](https://gist.github.com/freckletonj/b1fafa06230c672850ca2248e8b2a625/5dba8366fd9332105069cc83906c1109c55ebf75).

[**Solution Gist, thanks to Alec below**](https://gist.github.com/freckletonj/b1fafa06230c672850ca2248e8b2a625/b50b8c13597fd128ffd712d0d3a932145fcdd8a0)

```
type FA = "a" :-> String
type FB = "b" :-> Int
type AB = '[FA, FB]

ab :: Rec Identity AB
ab = "A" :*: 1 :*: RNil

tuplify :: (Show a) => Rec Identity '[a] -> [(String, String)]
tuplify = recordToList . rmap undefined -- ??????
-- tuplify ab = [("a", "A"), ("b", "1")]
```

If you care to try out what I've done so far, check out that [gist](https://gist.github.com/freckletonj/b1fafa06230c672850ca2248e8b2a625/5dba8366fd9332105069cc83906c1109c55ebf75), and it has well-thought-out examples and the errors I see:

Here is the hardware for refying in Composite [(`reifyDicts`):](https://github.com/ConferHealth/composite/blob/f5f396153a95d5b57d1e12ab3afcdc15327aefb6/composite-base/src/Composite/Record.hs#L239)

And the same for Vinyl [(`reifyConstraints`):](https://github.com/VinylRecords/Vinyl/blob/5ccbfb1ba237bb9a865f9dc29a59f69871d88c74/Data/Vinyl/Core.hs#L164)

AFAICT, the problem is that in something like `rmap`:

```
rmap :: (forall x. f x -> g x) -> Rec f rs -> Rec g rs
```

The mapped fn is defined `forall x`, but my `tuplify` is constrained, and I think the reification should move the constraint into the type (that's what `Dict`s are for), but, alas, no luck so far.

Comment: Are you avoiding the use of `reifyNames`? (Which seems ready made for this sort of thing...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get `composite` related stuff to install on my global Stack setup but the following should still work (I just copy-pasted relevant definitions). That said, I think a simple type-class based dispatch based on type is simpler here (since the constraints are non-trivial). With all of the right extensions enabled [1], you just need:

```
class Tuplify a where
  tuplify :: a -> [(String, String)]

instance Tuplify (Rec Identity '[]) where
  tuplify RNil = []

instance (Show t, KnownSymbol s, Tuplify (Rec Identity rs)) =>
           Tuplify (Rec Identity (s :-> t ': rs)) where
  tuplify (v :*: rs) = (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s), show v) : tuplify rs
```

Then, in GHCi:

```
ghci> tuplify ab
[("a","\"A\""),("b","1")]
```

---

If you really want to try the reifying constraint approach, you'll have to start by declaring a type class and instance for the particular constraint you want:

```
class ShowField a where 
  showField :: a -> (String, String)                                                                                

instance (KnownSymbol s, Show a) => ShowField (Identity (s :-> a)) where
  showField (Identity (Val v)) = (symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy s), show v)
```

Then it becomes more straightforward to use `reifyConstraints` and `rmap`:

```
tuplify' :: RecAll Identity rs ShowField => Rec Identity rs -> [(String, String)]
tuplify' xs = recordToList
            . rmap (\(Vinyl.Compose (Dict x)) -> Vinyl.Const $ showField x)
            $ reifyConstraint (Proxy :: Proxy ShowField) xs
```

I imagine something similar is possible with `reifyDicts`, although I wish there was a variant of it defined using `ValuesAllHave` instead of just `AllHave` (then we could bypass declaring a `ShowField` typeclass and do everything in just a function).

---

```
[1] extensions needed for first example

{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators       #-}
```

Comment: The `composite` library seems to be amazingly over-engineered for little to no benefit. E.g., you state there should be a variant of `reifyDicts` for `ValuesAllHave`; but there cannot be, without declaring an additional class to prove every `rs` is indeed a `:->` (e.g. `class IsAssoc a where isAssoc :: forall r . a -> (forall s v . ((s :-> v) ~ a) => r) -> r`) - your `ShowField` provides this proof. Also, `reifyDicts` uses `RecApplicative` to rebuild the spine of the list instead of just doing induction on the input. `composite` simply offers no easy way of performing this (simple) operation!

Comment: @user2407038 I completely agree. I also tried actively using the machinery they provide and the solutions I ended up with were twice as long and less clear than the ones I posted. :/

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct in assuming that Dependent Typing, or perhaps even just TypeInType, could make all of this easier since types, and kinds, and constraints (?), are more on the same level?

Comment: I suggest you consider `class Tuplify f ts where tuplify :: Rec f ts -> [(String, String)]`. This generalizes it a tad and IMO cleans it up.